# SublimeClang installation on ST3

Tags: clang, sublimetext3

Does anyone know if there is a special way of installing the plugin [SublimeClang](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang) in ST3 ?
In sublime text 2 there used to be a "lib" folder inside the sublime text folder that we used for a python link.
In my case, I installed python2.6 and I created a link that I put in a newly created "lib" folder (`/opt/sublime_text/lib`), but it does not work.
Any idea how it works with ST3 ?

Thank you very much in advance.

PS: Here is the output when I launch ST3.

```
reloading plugin SublimeClang.common
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py", line 73, in reload_plugin
m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
File "X/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 854, in _load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 981, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/jean/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeClang/common.py", line 135
  print msg
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
reloading plugin SublimeClang.errormarkers
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py", line 73, in reload_plugin
  m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
File "X/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 869, in _load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/jean/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeClang/errormarkers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from common import get_setting
ImportError: No module named 'common'
reloading plugin SublimeClang.staticanalyzer
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py", line 73, in reload_plugin
  m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
File "X/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 869, in _load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/jean/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeClang/staticanalyzer.py", line 31, in <module>
  import Queue
ImportError: No module named 'Queue'
reloading plugin SublimeClang.sublimeclang
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py", line 73, in reload_plugin
  m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
File "X/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 854, in _load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 981, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/jean/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeClang/sublimeclang.py", line 415
  print "found fast completions"
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
reloading plugin SublimeClang.translationunitcache
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py", line 73, in reload_plugin
  m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
File "X/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 854, in _load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 981, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/jean/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeClang/translationunitcache.py", line 103
    print "Have SublimeClang package: %s" % json
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you're on linux, you can also try [ClangComplete](https://github.com/pfultz2/ClangComplete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the import in the python files.

Comment: I'm getting these errors as well. What exactly did you change?

Comment: Sorry, I switched to CLion IDE which is a way better IDE (in my opinion) for C++ devs.

Answer (score 1):

From your link, it looks like the plugin is no longer being actively developed, and there's no mention of ST3 in the README. The error messages imply that a) the module is trying to load other modules that don't exist, or have moved, and b) the plugin is written in Python 2 (ST2 uses Python 2.6) whilst ST3 is based on Python 3.3. As a very brief example, the statement `print "Hello World!"` in Python 2 has been replaced with the function `print("Hello World!")` in Py3. As far as the missing module errors, ST3 is organized differently under the hood than ST2, and pretty much all but the most simplistic plugins need to be ported to the new API.

Comment: "From your link, it looks like the plugin is no longer being actively developed, and there's no mention of ST3 in the README". This is true but the author said few month ago that the plugin was [fixed](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10845) and works with ST3.

Comment: I also know that people have been using it with ST3 during the early and late beta. I was wondering if it was about the plugin looking for python2.6 ?